# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl cannot be cast

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am new to Hibernate Criteria , I found many examples using list.
Likes to know how a criteria object can be converted to Employee object.
Is it possible for Hibernate Criteria to return a class entity.

```
Employee emp=  (Employee) session.createCriteria(Employee.class,"a")
.createAlias("a.jobs", "j") 
.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id))
.add(Restrictions.eq("j.active", "1"));
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl cannot be cast to Employee.

jobs object is one to many relationship, trying to filteractive objects of jobs

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `list()` method

```
List<Employee> result =  (List<Employee>) session.createCriteria(Employee.class,"a")
.createAlias("a.jobs", "j") 
.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id))
.add(Restrictions.eq("j.active", "1")).list();
```

or `uniqueResult()`, but you will have an exception, if there is more than one record. If there is not any result `uniqueResult()` will return `null`.

```
Employee result = (Employee) session.createCriteria(Employee.class,"a")
.createAlias("a.jobs", "j") 
.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id))
.add(Restrictions.eq("j.active", "1")).uniqueResult();
```

Comment: As I am filtering by ID , it will be a single object.

Comment: @CorkKochi I update my answer. You can use only those two methods.

Answer (score 0):

If there is multiple records but you want single unique result to casting into the  model class without using list then you can also use following things :

```
Employee emp=  (Employee) session.createCriteria(Employee.class,"a")
.createAlias("a.jobs", "j") 
.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id))
.add(Restrictions.eq("j.active", "1")).setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
```